# Using UWP controls in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp, inkcanvas

I need to use InkCanvas (which is part of UWP Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls) in a WPF application. I know the WPF has InkCanvas too but they are totally different. The UWP InkCanvas has also InkAnalyzer which I need for handwriting recognition.

I created a fresh WPF app and added references bellow:

- ...NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll
- ...NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml.dll
- Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd
- Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd

In MainWindow.xaml.cs When I try to create a new InkCanvas I get an error:

> System.Exception: 'The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))'

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.InkCanvas myPage = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.InkCanvas();
}
```

My question is, is there a way to use UWP controls (especially InkCanvas in my case)in a WPF app?

Comment: Why are you "creating" `InkCanvas` if you want it in `MainWindow.xaml` just write it as `XAML`.
`<InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvas" ....></InkCanvas>`

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot embed UWP controls in a WPF Window. You can *spawn* a UWP window from WPF, which can then host UWP controls -  because different dispatchers, etc.

Comment: You get me wrong. I need the InkCanvas that belongs to UWP not WPF.

Answer (score 5):

Not possible today, but it's something that is on the roadmap for a future update.

Comment: Is this for all controls and other UWP functionality? UWP has some nice new features but the whole concept of the UWP platform is useless to me and my team as desktop developers..

Comment: I just watched the build video where this is mentioned. The concerning thing  however is that it does not specify what the end product is. Will it still be an exe? The current UWP packages are not fit for internal business deployment. I would be all for an internally hosted package manager of some sort but not the windows store.

Comment: It's a separate topic, but we are also making lots of improvements to the UWP packaging and deployment feature, especially to make it fit for internal business deployment, outside of Store. The Fall Creators update already brought a lot of improvements to close gaps with ClickOnce (installing package from web, auto-update for side-loads, etc.) and there is more coming this Spring. Are you using ClickOnce today or something else?

Comment: Yep we are using ClickOnce at the moment. Good to hear there's something on its way for internal deployment.

Comment: I need the InkCanvas that belongs to UWP not WPF.

<uwpcontrols:Page x:Class="WPFInkRecognition.UWPPage"
        ...........
        xmlns:uwpcontrols="clr-namespace:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;assembly=Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract"
        >
    <uwpcontrols:InkCanvas></uwpcontrols:InkCanvas>
</uwpcontrols:Page>

It doesn't even recognize uwpcontrols:Page and uwpcontrols:InkCanvas

Comment: I understand. And the answer is: not possible today. We are working to enable it in a future update to Windows 10.

Comment: Hi , is it possible now? the first google result is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-host-controls.
Confirming that it should work, but not how.
The second google result is this answer, so maybe update the answer please. (With a link to an example)

Comment: Support for this is coming in the fall 2018 update of Windows 10.